# What's the opposite of `x in y` in a list comprehension/generator expression?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, any, in-operator, generator-expression

An example I came up was something like this:

```
identified_characters = ["a","c","f","h","l","o"]
word = "alcachofa#"
if any(character in word for character not in identified_characters):
    print("there are unidentified characters inside the word")
else:
    print("there aren't unidentified characters inside the word")
```

but the `not` brings a syntax error, so I was thinking that if there was an `out` (opposite of `in` I guess) function theoretically you could change the `not in` and keep the syntax.

I also thought the logic of the given result should be the opposite of the `any` function, but looking up I saw that ppl came out that the opposite of `any` should be `not all`, in which case wouldn't work here.

Comment: Why do you think "pycharm" has any role in this question's context?

Comment: it's just to clarify that I'm working with PyCharm, I'm kinda new to python and Keras, and I know that newbies that arent fluid english speakers like me have a tendency to include the name of the API they are working with while googling

Comment: You're warm. `character not in identified_characters` **is in general actually a legal expression**, but you can't simply say `for x not in y` in a list-comprehension/generator expression. You just need to add an `if`-clause to the end of the list comprehension: `character in word if character not in identified_characters`. But anyway, as people are pointing out here, `set()` is really what you want in this case, you can do all the set union/inclusion/exclusion operations on your letters in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't loop over every possible item not in `identified_characters`; there are unaccountably many. That doesn't even make sense in concept.

To achieve what you want (checking if there are unidentified characters (characters not in `identified_characters`) in `word`), you will have to loop over `word`, not the complement of `identified_characters`.

```py
identified_characters = {"a", "c", "f", "h", "l", "o"}

word = "alcachofa#"
if any(character not in identified_characters for character in word):
    print("there are unidentified characters inside the word")
else:
    print("there aren't unidentified characters inside the word")
```

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias: [Are you sure?](https://ideone.com/xEir45)

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias I just ran it and it printed `there are unidentified characters inside the word`. You're probably running an old version or something.

Comment: actually let me take that back, it actually works. maybe I just read wrong the output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `not` in the `for` statement, use it on the `character in word` part.

```py
identified_characters=["a","c","f","h","l","o"]
word="alcachofa#"
if any(character not in identified_characters for character in word):
    print("there are unidentified characters inside the word")
else:
    print("there aren't unidentified characters inside the word")
```

For loops can use `in` but not `not in` because they have no idea what `not in` means! For loops are meant to iterate through lists or any iterable and can't iterate through what is not in an iterable as they have no idea *what* is "not in" the iterable. You can also use `not all` in the following way:

Comment: Your code treats `identified_characters` as a list of required characters rather than a list of permitted characters.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Fixed it